# Activate VIM folding markers via modeline

Tags: vim, folding, modeline

I'm trying to figure out why folding doesn't work with multi-line comments and I have no ideas.

Let's consider such example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
panic(void) /* {{{ */
{
    abort();
}
/* }}} */

void
say_hello(void) /* {{{ */
{
    printf("Hello, World \n");  
}
/* }}} */

void
say_goodbye(void) /* {{{ */
{
    printf("Good Bye, World \n");
    panic();
}
/* }}} */

int
main(void) /* {{{ */
{
    void (*message) (void);

    message = say_goodbye;
    message();

    message = say_hello;
    message();

    return 0;
}
/* }}} */
```

The following modelines works as expected. While opening the file, I see that all the code is folded:

```
/* vim600: set noet sw=4 ts=4 fdm=marker : */
```

and

```
// vim600: noet sw=4 ts=4 fdm=marker
```

[image]

The command `:verbose set syntax filetype foldmethod foldexpr`

shows expected output

```
  syntax=c
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  filetype=c
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  foldmethod=marker
        Last set from modeline
  foldexpr=0
```

However, any variations with multi-line comments do not give the desired result. For example:

```
/*
 * vim600: noet sw=4 ts=4 fdm=marker
 * vim<600: noet sw=4 ts=4
 */
```

or even

```
/* Modeline for ViM {{{
 * vim: noet:sw=4:ts=4
 * vim600: noet:sw=4:ts=4:fdm=marker
 * }}} */
```

Will not automatically fold the code when opening a file:

```
  syntax=c
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  filetype=c
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  foldmethod=manual
  foldexpr=0
```

Comment: Works for me. What does `:set modelines?` return?

Comment: `:set modelines?` returns `modelines=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the setting of `modelines`. Vim searches the first or last modelines lines for a modeline. With modelines set to 1 the modeline has to be either on the first or last line of the file.

The default value of modelines is 5. This would work for your examples.

See `:help modelines`